# Sockets don't work as excpected with LAN or NET, but perfectly locally

Tags: java, sockets

I'm programming a network software with Java, but I have a real problem using my application through a "true" network.

Let a software be a host, and listening for client connexions.
Here is my Server loop :

```
public void run() {                                                 
    while (mServerSocket != null) {                                        
        try {                                                              
            Socket wClient = mServerSocket.accept();                       
            System.out.println("Client connecté");                         
            wClient.setSoTimeout(50);                                      
            wClient.setTcpNoDelay(false);                                  
            Client c = new Client(wClient);                                
            synchronized(this) {                                           
                mWaitingClients.add(c);                                    
                c.start();                                                 
            }                                                              
        } catch(Exception ex) {                                              
            System.out.println("Server error : " + ex.getMessage());       
        }                                                                  
    }                                                                      
}
```

When a client tried to connect to the server, I use this function :

```
public Client connect(InetAddress addr, int port) throws Exception {
    Socket socket = new Socket(addr, port);                        
    socket.setSoTimeout(50);                                       
    socket.setTcpNoDelay(false);                                   
    Client c = new Client(socket);                                 
    c.start();                                                     
    return c;                                                      
}
```

And here is the client loop :

```
public void run() {                                                             
    try {                                                                       
        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(mSocket.getOutputStream());                                                                                 
        ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(mSocket.getInputStream()); 

        while(mSocket.isConnected() && !mSocket.isClosed()) {                   
            for (int i = 0; i < mOutMessages.size(); i++) {                     
                Message msg = mOutMessages.get(i);                              
                out.writeObject(msg);                                           
            }                                                                   
            out.flush();                                                        
            mOutMessages.clear();                                               

            Thread.sleep(50);                                                   
            out.reset();                                                        

            while(true) {                                                       
                try {                                                           
                    Message m = (Message) in.readObject();                      
                    mInMessages.add(m);                                         
                } catch (Exception e) {                                         
                    break;                                                      
                }                                                               
            }                                                                   

            Thread.sleep(50);                                                   
        }                                                                       
    } catch(Exception ex) {                                                     
        try {                                                                   
            mSocket.close();                                                    
        } catch(Exception exx) {                                                
            exx.printStackTrace();                                              
        }                                                                       
        ex.printStackTrace();                                                   
    }                                                                           
}
```

Some other parts of the program do Message and put them in the Output list of the Client (mOutMessages).
Some other parts of the program read Message from the mInMessages of the Client.

But something is wrong with this. It works fine locally (server and client on the same computer), but fail or is hazardous (some messages are sent but never received)  using two computers (with LAN or through the Internet).
Server ever detect connexions from the clients, send "handshake" messages to the client, but the client never receives them.

I'm more a C programmer than a Java one, and I never had this kind of problem using libc Sockets, so, why my way of doing is wrong ?

Thank you !

Edit :
My Server is created using this function :

```
public void open(int port) throws Exception {
    mServerSocket = new ServerSocket(port);  
    start(); // Call the run mentionned above.                                
}
```

Edit :
Here is my solution, maybe it's not perfect but it works !

```
public void run() {                                                        
    try {                                                                  
        BufferedOutputStream buf_out = new BufferedOutputStream(           
            mSocket.getOutputStream()                                      
        );                                                                 
        BufferedInputStream buf_in = new BufferedInputStream(              
            mSocket.getInputStream()                                       
        );                                                                 
        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(buf_out);          
        out.flush();                                                       
        ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(buf_in);              

        while(mSocket.isConnected() && !mSocket.isClosed()) {              
            for (int i = 0; i < mOutMessages.size(); i++) {                
                Message msg = mOutMessages.get(i);                         
                out.writeObject(msg);                                      
                out.flush();                                               
            }                                                              
            mOutMessages.clear();                                          
            out.reset();                                                   

            while(true) {                                                  
                try {                                                      
                    Message m = (Message) in.readObject();                 
                    mInMessages.add(m);                                    
                } catch (Exception e) {                                    
                    break;                                                 
                }                                                          
            }                                                              
        }                                                                  
    } catch(Exception ex) {                                                
        try {                                                              
            mSocket.close();                                               
        } catch(Exception exx) {                                           
            exx.printStackTrace();                                         
        }                                                                  
        ex.printStackTrace();                                              
    }
```

Comment: When it "fails", what happens then?

Comment: The server write messages in the ObjectOoutputStream, but the client never see them.

Comment: How do you create your Server ? it's probably the issue

Comment: I updated main post.

Comment: How do you know the server sends messages? How do you know the client doesn't receive them? Are you running in a debugger? Do you have debug output to the console? And what ports are you using? Are there any firewalls between the server and the client? How are they set up? Have you tried looking at the networks packets being sent/received with e.g. [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) or similar tool?

Comment: I know that the client messages are sent because the server notify that he received them.
I know the client didn't receive message from the server because it didn't notice that he received them. Do you think it could be a problem like a "false send" ?
I will try with WireShark to see if they are effectively sent.
Thank you

Comment: EDIT: Ok with wireshark, I see that I receive the message, but the program don't see them...
Then, when I try to connect and I get the answer from the server (that i received), I get a malformed packet :
1977 19.404919000 2.1.172.130 192.168.0.10 IRC 738 Response (xp) (comparatort) (t)[Malformed Packet]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand right, both client and server use the `run` method. If both client and server happen to write sufficiently large messages (not fitting in involved buffers) at the same time then you get a **deadlock** because neither partner advances to reading (which would drain full buffers). Due to network delays, this might only happen in the non-local scenario, i.e. there may be enough time to pile up enough messages in the `mOutMessages` buffer.

Note that documentation of `Socket.setSoTimeout` (which you used) only says that it affects read()s. (For example, in my JDK, ObjectOutputStream seems to use a BlockDataOutputStream with a buffer size of 1024 bytes).

I recommend to either use a separate thread for reading/writing or (if you know the maximum messages size) use a sufficiently large buffer (by wrapping the `SocketOutputStream` in a `BufferedOutputStream`). If you opt for larger buffers, you may also want to write one message at a time (and try to read messages after each).

Comment: Ok you are totally right, I just put my streams into Buffers and now it works perfectly. I edit my message to show you what I done (it's not perfect but it works oh yeah !).
Thank you !

Comment: Good to hear that it works now. According to my JDK sources you are using a buffer of just 8192 bytes (default) now. You might want to explicitly pass a comfortable buffer size when constructing the BufferedOutputStream in order not to be dependent on Java runtime internals (i.e. default buffer sizes) - or to add some extra space in case object sizes increase in the future.

Comment: Ok, I set their size to 512kb, guessin' would be better.
Thank you for all :)